# Welcome message with embed is not showing

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

So I made a bot that will send welcome messages in a channel to new members.
My code is supposed to work because it didn't send any errors in my console, but my bot didn't send the welcome message.

I tried many things:

- Made the embed an object (nope)
- Made 4 long different codes (all not working)
- Searched the web and watched some tuts (no error in the console but not sending)

I'm using discord.js@v12

Code:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  // Finds the channel name from the array
  function channelNamesFilter(channel) {
    let channelNames = ['name', 'welcome', 'welcoming', 'greeting', 'general', 'hello'];

    if (channelNames.includes(channel.name)) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }


  const welcome = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#F2CC0D')
    .setTitle('Welcome To The Server!')
    .addFields({
      name: member.nickname
    }, {
      name: '\n ',
      value: 'Make sure to visit the FAQ and Rules channel (if there are)!'
    })
    .setImage(member.user.avatarURL)

  let filteredChannels = member.guild.channels.cache.filter(channelNamesFilter);
  filteredChannels.forEach(element => element.send(welcome));
});
```

Comment: If you run `console.log(filteredChannels)` after you declared the variable, what does it log?

Comment: It said `Collection(0) [Map] {}`

Comment: Sorry for bad answer, i was on mobile and didnt read your code correctly. I am finding new answer.

Comment: When you console.log the filteredChannels collection, what will it be?

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Wait, try console.log(filteredChannels.length), because i forgot, if the legth is there, when you console.log collection and i cant test it now.

Comment: @doc.Chocholoušek It's the first thing I asked in the first comment: it shows that `filteredChannels` is an empty Collection

Comment: @Lenin it seems that the problem is in the filter function, you should try debugging that. Assuming you have at least one channel with one of those names, try putting `console.log(channel.name)` and `console.log(channelNames.includes(channel.name))` in the code to see whether the channel is filtered correctly

Comment: sorry i answered late i was figuring something out.
I tried:
`console.log(filteredChannels.length);` result= `undefined`
`console.log(filteredChannels);` result= `Collection(0) [Map]`
`console.log(channelNamesFilter);` result= `[Function: channelNamesFilter]`
`console.log(channelNamesFilter.length);` result= `1`

Comment: Sry, for getting collection size its .size(). But as Frederico Grandi saied, try to go inside the filter function and before returning false console.log the channel name.

Comment: `size` is a property not a method by the way (don’t call it)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just solved it after like researching for more than 10 hours! I finally got it!

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member =>{

  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name.includes('welcome'));
    if (!channel) return;

//send through channel
const welcomegreet = {
  color: 0xF2CC0D,
  title: `**WELCOME TO THE SERVER, ${member.user.tag} !!**`,
  description: `I hope you will enjoy it here! \n A place full of chaos and wonder!`,
  thumbnail: {
    url: member.user.avatarURL(),
  },
  fields:[
  {
    name: 'Need Help?',
    value: 'Please read the FAQ and Rules Channels (if there are)! \n Have Fun at the Server! CHEERS  !',
    inline: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Join Me!',
    value: 'Do: `h.help` for entertainment and profanities!',
    inline: false
  }
 ],
 timestamp: new Date(),
};

//send through dm
const welcome = {
  color: 0xF2CC0D,
  title: `**WELCOME TO THE SERVER, ${member.user.tag} !!**`,
  description: `I hope you will enjoy it here! \n A place full of chaos and wonder!`,
  thumbnail: {
    url: member.user.avatarURL(),
  },
  timestamp: new Date(),
};
member.send({ embed: welcomegreet });
channel.send({ embed: welcome });
```

Thanks guys for trying to help me, even though It didn't get too close to the amswer.
I tested this out and it worked splendidly!
note:
This only works if the channel has the word "welcome"